# Values attained by $|G/Z(G)|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

So I was working through some problems in a book on $p$-groups and noticed that
$p$-groups have some really nice properties. So I started computing what the values of $|G/Z(G)|$ for $p$-groups. I decided to see what it would be and found that it cannot attain the value of $p$. I am interested in the whethere $|G/Z(G)|$ can attain all other powers of $p$?

In general I am interesting in the values that $|G/Z(G)|$ can achieve.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For example, any $n$ such that every group of order $n$ is cyclic (e.g. the $n$ such that $(n,\varphi(n))=1$) are not attainable. For then, $G/Z(G)$ would necessarily be cyclic, so that $G$ is abelian so that $|G/Z(G)|=1$ . I don't know if this is the only restriction though... This is if I am understanding your question correctly: characterize $n$ which occur as $|G/Z(G)|$ for some group $G$.

Comment: PS (+1), interesting question! Also, the e.g. in my last question should be i.e. The numbers $n$ such that every group of order $n$ is cyclic are precisely the $n$ such that $(n,\varphi(n))=1$.

Comment: Okay, so the primes are out immediately.    That is indeed my question  =)

Comment: The primes, and more generally products $p_1\ldots p_m$ such that $p_i\not\equiv 1\mod p_j$ for all $i,j$. Also, I'm a little confused by the indexing of your sets $\psi_n$ though. I see no dependence on $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to break it up to try to solve a slightly more general problem, but I forgot. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Here are some comments, but not a complete solution.  First, if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots$ and all the $\alpha_i>1$, your results on $p$-groups imply $n\in\psi$. Second, if $n$ is even - say $n=2m$ - then the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is such that $D_{2n}/Z(D_{2n})$ has order $n$.  So all even numbers are in $\psi$. The odd $n$ case is much harder.

Comment: There are certain numbers that cannot be in $\psi$: as already remarked, the cyclic numbers; also, abelian numbers with one or more of the $\alpha_i=1$ (as an example, $45\notin\psi$); there are other cases, but they seem harder to classify.  Note that the much harder problem of finding groups that are central quotients of other groups is the *classification of capable groups* problem, of which there is much literature (a lot by our our own @ArturoMagidin).

Comment: @SteveD Why can't we have abelian numbers with one or more of the $\alpha_i=1$? We know we can't have $G/Z(G)$ be cyclic, but what does having it be abelian with a cyclic factor tell us? Sorry if this is a stupid question.:)

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Not stupid at all! It comes from an article of Baer, which essentially initiated the study of capable groups: *Groups with Preassigned Center and Central Quotient*.  It is the Corollary to his Existence Theorem that is of most concern here.

Comment: @SteveD Ah, interesting! Thanks, I'll have to check that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you found that $|G/Z(G)|$ cannot be prime is essentially the only restriction for $p$-groups:

> For every $k\geq 2$ and every $p\in\mathbb{P}$ there exists a finite  $p$-group $G$ such that $|G/Z(G)|=p^k$.

Proof: Let $q:=p^{k-1}$ and consider the matrix group $\begin{pmatrix}1&\mathbb{F}_p&\mathbb{F}_q \\ &1&\mathbb{F}_q \\ && 1\end{pmatrix}$ which has order $p^{2k-1}$ and center of order $p^{k-1}$ (the top right corner) which gives us a center quoient of order $p^k$ as desired. QED.

Observe that by taking direct products of such groups one can easily write down examples of $|G/Z(G)|=n$ for every natural number $n>1$ in which every prime factor that occurs, occurs at least twice. This is because $Z(G_1\times G_2)=Z(G_1)\times Z(G_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

In connection of this question it might be interesting to note that bounding the size of $G/Z(G)$ for a given finite group $G$ has some interesting history. For a given finite group [Jordan's theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Jordan-Schur) gives an upper bound on the size of $G/Z(G)$ in terms of the degree of the smallest faithful representation of $G$.